# Store all incoming JSON messages in array and retrieve using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My application receives JSON data from another application every 10 minutes. I have a requirement to store the incoming JSON messages and when a new message comes in. I need to compare and do calculations based on the data from both the messages. How can I do it?

I tried like this(just testing - not with actual data) :

```
var inputData = []
inputData = JSON.stringify(data1)
jsonArray.push(inputData)
var jsonArray = []
inputData = JSON.stringify(data2)
jsonArray.push(inputData)

for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonArray[i])
        if ((data3.x === jsonData.x))
        {    
            document.write("\n")
            document.write(jsonData.x);
        }
}
```

But my question is, whenever a new message comes in, this module is invoked and the `jsonArray` is getting initialized. So, how we can make the array or (previous JSON message) available in the module when a new message comes? Do I need to have a second array in the code? Thank you so much for your help.

Here is a sample of incoming message:

```
data1 = {"Battery":4.28,"moisture":15.88,"temperature":28,"messageType":"MOIST_TEMP","deviceId":"A371A","timestamp":"2019-12-02T02:53:25.000Z"}
```

Comment: make jsonArray global variable

Comment: can you add the incoming message format

Comment: @NarendraChouhan ... i have added the incoming message format

Comment: @LoveCoding Great, i have added the logic please check it

Answer (score 1):

I think You can do this way **Hope this Helps**

```js
//Suppose the Incoming Message is this
let incomingMessage = { "Battery": 9.780, "moisture": 75.88, "temperature": 36, "messageType": "MOIST_TEMP", "deviceId": "A371A", "timestamp": "2019-12-02T02:53:25.000Z" }

// The JsonArray you have right Now which stores the incoming Message
let jsonArray = [
    { "Battery": 4.28, "moisture": 15.88, "temperature": 28, "messageType": "MOIST_TEMP", "deviceId": "A371A", "timestamp": "2019-12-02T02:53:25.000Z" },
    { "Battery": 9.00, "moisture": 77.88, "temperature": 32, "messageType": "MOIST_TEMP", "deviceId": "A371A", "timestamp": "2019-12-02T02:53:25.000Z" },
    { "Battery": 4.28, "moisture": 15.88, "temperature": 28, "messageType": "MOIST_TEMP", "deviceId": "A371A", "timestamp": "2019-12-02T02:53:25.000Z" }
]

let isExist = []

//check that incoming message exits in the jsonArray 
for (let i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    let found = true;
    for (let p in incomingMessage) {
        if (incomingMessage.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (jsonArray[i][p] !== incomingMessage[p]) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    isExist.push(found)
}
//Push if Incoming message doesn't exist
if(isExist.indexOf(true)<=-1){
 jsonArray.push(incomingMessage)
}
console.log(jsonArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of problems you need to ask yourself **what are the steps?**

Let's write those down:

1. initialize array of data. Since no data has been loaded, it's just an empty array.
2. Have a function set on an interval make a call to some endpoint
3. If the request from point #2 goes through, look through the newly received data and do some comparisons with our previously received data.
4. add the data to the array

Let's rough that out. I'm going to literally just take the above list and make it comments. From there, I'll do the necessary actions in code below it.

```js
// 1. initialize array of data. Since no data has been loaded, it's just an empty array.
const received = [];
// 2. Have a function set on an interval make a call to some endpoint
const interval = setInterval(async () => {

  // 3. If the request from point #2 goes through, look through the newly received data and do some comparisons with our previously received data.

  const data = await fetch('https://example.com/').then(res => res.json());
  for (let incomin_data of data) {
    for (let received_data of received) {
      // do your comparisons of stuff here....  
    }
  }

  // 4. add the data to the array
  received.push(...data);

}, 10000); // remember, 10000 ms = 10 seconds
```

**Small note:** the above code loops through all the data in the newly received information *and* all the previously received data. While this isn't a huge issue for smaller amounts of data, if left completely alone there will come a time that you could theoretically freeze the browser. Alter the for loop structure to ensure that you are doing as few loops through both full sets of data as possible. Doesn't mean much when it's 10 rows in either case, but if you're pulling huge amounts of data, the received array could get very large very quickly and that could cause problems down the line.

### Edit

Proof of concept

```js
const received = [];

const interval = setInterval(()=> {
  received.push(received.length);
  
  console.log(received);
}, 1500);
```

Comment: When the next message comes , the code runs and this ```received``` array will be initialized right ?  I need to make the data available in the array till the message from the same device comes. So the array needs to keep on storing incoming data.

Comment: Since the received array is declared outside of the interval function it is not deleted or otherwise undone in each consecutive call.

Comment: I will edit this with a similar proof of concept to show you what I mean -- it is sometimes easier to see these things than it is to explain them

Comment: @LoveCoding please see the edited section to show how the received array is not reset, and instead grows as time goes on.